# How to get action of button in Swift MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, button

I am trying to set up zoom for a game where you click on a button to zoom in, and another to zoom out (which will be part of the UI).

I am having problems getting the input of the buttons to the code. I can read that the button is not pressed, but I cannot figure out how to read if it is pressed.

Looking through the API reference gave me the idea to try using the "state" of the button, but it always returns 0, even when the button is pressed. This could be because the update function does not update as fast as the button's state changes.

Here is my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        cam = SKCameraNode()
        cam.xScale = 1
        cam.yScale = 1
        self.camera = cam
        self.addChild(cam)
        cam.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        setUpUI()
    }

    func setUpUI(){
        let button1Rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 80, width: 80, height: 40)
        let zoomIn = NSButton(frame: button1Rect) //place a button in the Rect
        zoomIn.setButtonType(NSMomentaryPushInButton)
        zoomIn.title = "Zoom In"
        zoomIn.alternateTitle = "Zoom In"
        zoomIn.acceptsTouchEvents = true
        view?.addSubview(zoomIn) //put button on screen
        let button2Rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 80, height: 40)
        let zoomOut = NSButton(frame: button2Rect) //place a button in the Rect
        zoomOut.setButtonType(NSMomentaryPushInButton)
        zoomOut.title = "Zoom Out"
        zoomOut.alternateTitle = "Zoom Out"
        zoomOut.acceptsTouchEvents = true
        view?.addSubview(zoomOut) //put button on screen
        if zoomIn.state == 1{ //this loop is never true no matter how many times I press the button
            print("zoom")
        }
    }
}
```

I did cut out some of the code involving the mouse as it is not relevant.

Comment: The update function updates plenty fast enough to catch a button state change.   This code you've posted only checks your state once, and it doesn't listen for changes.  Put your `if zoomIn.state` statement in the update function.

Comment: I put it in the 'setUpUI()' function, which should work as it is in the 'update()' function. I do want to put it in the 'update()' function, but the problem is that the buttons are defined in the 'setUpUI()' function and when I put the zoomIn.state into the update function it says it is an unresolved identifier.

Comment: Just move your `let zoomIn` declaration line to the scene scope.  Anywhere outside of a function.  Then you can use that variable in any function you need to including the update function.

Comment: Is there any reason my idea to continuously check the button's state will not work? And how would I create a function that is called when the button is pressed?

Comment: Checking button state should work just fine.  I'm not sure it's the cleanest or most efficient way, but will work.

Comment: Setting it outside of the GameScene seemed to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is from TheValyreanGroup.

Simply define the button outside of the setUpUI() function (outside of the GameScene or within it works, outside of the GameScene is easier).